# Message: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using an Library to write files in .ini format.

Now this is my my write function:

```
function write($file = NULL, $data = array(), $sections = TRUE) {
    $this->data = (!empty($data)) ? $data : $this->data;
    $this->file = ($file) ? $file : $this->file;
    $this->sections = $sections;
    $content = NULL;

    if ($this->sections) {
        foreach ($this->data as $section => $data) {
            $content .= '[' . $section . ']' . PHP_EOL;
            foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    foreach ($val as $v) {
                        $content .= $key . '[] = ' . (is_numeric($v) ? $v : '"' . $v . '"') . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                } elseif (empty($val)) {
                    $content .= $key . ' = ' . PHP_EOL;
                } else {
                    $content .= $key . ' = ' . (is_numeric($val) ? $val : '"' . $val . '"') . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
            $content .= PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                foreach ($val as $v) {
                    $content .= $key . '[] = ' . (is_numeric($v) ? $v : '"' . $v . '"') . PHP_EOL;
                }
            } elseif (empty($val)) {
                $content .= $key . ' = ' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $content .= $key . ' = ' . (is_numeric($val) ? $val : '"' . $val . '"') . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    return (($handle = fopen($this->file, 'w')) && fwrite($handle, trim($content)) && fclose($handle)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

And i write my content i give the file like this:

```
                $file = $path.$filename;

                $ini = new INI($file);



                    // Save settings to file
                $ini->write($insert);
```

ON VAR_DUMP($ini); i get :

```
object(INI)[76]
  public 'file' => string 'C:/wamp/www/bizrtc/uploads/test1.ini' (length=36)
  public 'data' => 
    array (size=3)
      'INIDetails' => 
        array (size=11)
          'SipUserName' => string '' (length=0)
          'Password' => string '' (length=0)
          'Domain' => string '' (length=0)
          'Proxy' => string '' (length=0)
          'Port' => string '' (length=0)
          'SipAuthName' => string '' (length=0)
          'DisplayName' => string '' (length=0)
          'ServerMode' => string '' (length=0)
          'UCServer' => string '' (length=0)
          'UCUserName' => string '' (length=0)
          'UCPassword' => string '' (length=0)
      'DialPlan' => 
        array (size=3)
          'DP_Exception' => string '' (length=0)
          'DP_Rule1' => string '' (length=0)
          'DP_Rule2' => string '' (length=0)
      'Advanced' => 
        array (size=14)
          'OperationMode' => string '' (length=0)
          'MutePkey' => string '' (length=0)
          'Codec' => string '' (length=0)
          'PTime' => string '' (length=0)
          'AudioMode' => string '' (length=0)
          'SoftwareAEC' => string '' (length=0)
          'EchoTailLength' => string '' (length=0)
          'PlaybackBuffer' => string '' (length=0)
          'CaptureBuffer' => string '' (length=0)
          'JBPrefetchDelay' => string '' (length=0)
          'JBMaxDelay' => string '' (length=0)
          'SipToS' => string '' (length=0)
          'RTPToS' => string '' (length=0)
          'LogLevel' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'sections' => boolean true
```

where i am wrong? what should i do to let this work?

Comment: check the value in `$this->file`.

Comment: @urfusion when i var_dump($ini) i get this public 'file' => string 'C:/wamp/www/bizrtc/uploads/test1.ini' (length=36)

Comment: you are passing `$insert` in `$ini->write($insert);`.  where is the value of `$insert`?

Comment: @urfusion $insert is an array i pass , those are the values i get from POST

Comment: that's why you are getting this error. you are passing `$insert` to `$file = NULL`. while `$insert` is an array not the path of file.

Comment: as you see the dump i am giving a path as string the insert as data and sections to be true!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104977/discussion-between-rajan-and-urfusion).

Answer (score 2):

Without entire class and line number of an error it can be difficult to guess. The method seems to be ok, at least the part with fopen. To me it seems like your property has been overriden somewhere else. Try to make it private and see what happens, maybe this will help you to spot the problem.