# PHP code snippet is not able to create file

Tags: php, html, forms, file-handling

I have a form in an HTML with action="file.php" and method="post"

But this "file.php" is not able to create a file:

```
<?php
$my_file = 'username.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file,'w');
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value)  
{
    if($variable == 'email')
    {
        fwrite($handle, $variable);
        fwrite($handle, "=");
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    }
}

fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

But could be the problem ?

Comment: You should check that your `fopen` call succeeded. You should also post any error messages you got here.

Comment: Not getting any error message but the file 'username.txt' is just not created,

Comment: I have no prior knowledge in php, just working on a project

Comment: Silly oversight but make sure the path is writable and that you have the write permission on the directory

Comment: how to give it the permissions to write?

Comment: PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/file.php

Comment: If you’re using an FTP client you can CHMOD the directory 777 (most clients allow you to right click the directory and set permissions) you should really have a /temp directory, judging by your error on fclose() you never opened a stream to create a file to close, so I’m assuming it’s a permission issue (I could be wrong but it’s worth a shot)

Comment: Thanks @llan, I changed the permissions of directory and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Message: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716634/message-fopen-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-path-array-given)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, Make sure you have write permission for the file.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("username.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$fName = "members.txt";
$file = fopen($fName, "w");

if ($file !== false)
{
    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value)  
    {
        if($variable == 'email')
        {
            fwrite($file, $variable ."=". $value .PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
else
{
    Echo("The file ". $fName ." is unable to open!");
}
```